# Load Database values to hash

Tags: perl

i wish to seek wisdom on an issue with troubles me. I have a database query that returns such result :

```
Ingredients  ID
  fish        1
  salt        1
  pepper      1
  tomato      2  
  veggies     2
  milk        2
   .
   .
   .
```

How may i store this values into a hash using the ID as key and the ingredients as values ? 
Something like this :

- Key(1) values (fish,salt,pepper)
- key(2) values (tomato,veggies,milk) etc

*Within the block*

```
my %results;

   while( %result = $dbh->fetchrow_as_hashtable() ){
        %results{'ID'} = %result{'ID'};
        %results{'Ingredients'} = %result{'Ingredients'}

        }
```

The issue why i am confused is 1 ID(meal) could have many ingredients.Putting the extracted data into a hashmap confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each record will be returned as a hashref if you call `fetchrow_hashref`. You can use that to form a hash of arrayrefs.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute;

my %result;
while ( my $rec = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    # @{...} dereferences the hash value as an array
    # and a value is then pushed into that array
    push @{ $result{ $rec->{ID} } }, $rec->{Ingredients};
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%result;
```

`%result` should now contain:

```
%result = (
    1 => [qw( fish salt pepper )],
    2 => [qw(tomato veggies milk )],
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a problem, the print statement returns nothing :(

Comment: can you verify that records are being returned in the while loop?

Comment: @stevanl Please how may i sort the keys to appear in ASCENDING order

Comment: You'll need to sort the keys as you read them, e.g. `foreach my $key ( sort keys %result ) { print "$key => $result{$key}\n" }`

Answer (score 0):

I gues you should use a hast of arrays, like this:

```
%results = (
'1' =>  [ 'fish','salt','pepper'],
'2' => [ 'tomato' ,'veggies','milk'],
);
```

or you should  just push ingredients to the array, like:

```
push( @{$results{1}}, 'salad'))
```